# Average distance from origin in a random walk on the integer number line

Tags: integers, random-walk, multinomial-distribution

In a random integer walk along a number line (each step 0.5 probability of moving right and 0.5 probability of moving left), **what is the average distance from the origin during the walk**?

Other questions on here ask something that sounds like this, but I'm not sure if they are talking about the average *during* the walk, or just your expected distance at the *end* of the walk.

---

Follow-up question: if you have the answer for the *end* of a walk of length $n$ (call it $w(n)$), could you get the *during* walk average by doing the average $\sum_1^n{w(i)}/n$, or would that not work because the distance at each step is not independent of the distance of the previous steps?

Answer (score 2):

Assume without loss of generality that the random walk starts at 0. Let $X_i$ be a random variable with $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$, so that the random walk is represented by the random variable $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. At time $m$, the distance from the origin is $|S_m|$. Let us compute $E[|S_{2m}|] = E[|X_1 + \cdots + X_{2m}|]$.

The random walk can only be at an even position, so $P(|S_{2m}| = j) = 0$ for $j$ odd. Now let $2k$ be an even integer in $[0,2m]$. By symmetry,
$$P(X_1 + \cdots + X_{2m} = 2k) = P(X_1 + \cdots X_{2m} = -2k)$$
Let us compute the probability that the walker is at $2k$. If the walker moves $j$ steps forward and $2m - j$ steps backwards, he is at $2j - 2m = 2k$. Thus we require $k+m$ many $+1$'s. The sum of the $X_i$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $p = 1/2$ and $n = 2m$, so that
$$P(S_{2m} = 2k) = \binom{2m}{m+k} \left(\frac12\right)^{2m}$$
and
$$P(|S_{2m}| = 2k) = \binom{2m}{m+k}  \left(\frac12\right)^{2m-1}.$$
Computing the expectation,
\begin{align*}
E[|S_{2m}|] &=
\sum_{k=0}^{2m} k P(|S_{2m}| = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} 2k P(|S_{2m}| = 2k)   \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} k \left(\frac12\right)^{2m-2}\binom{2m}{k+m} \\
&= \frac{m+1}{2^{2m-1}}\binom{2 m}{m+1} \\
&= \frac{m+1}{2^{2m-1}} \cdot \frac{(2m)!}{(m+1)!(m-1)!} \\
&= \frac{m+1}{2^{2m-1}} \cdot \frac{(2m)!}{m!m!} \cdot \frac{m}{m+1} \\
&= \frac{2m}{2^{2m}} \binom{2m}{m}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, one can show that
$$E[|S_{2m+1}|] = \frac{2m+1}{2^{2m}} \binom{2m}{m}.$$
Now we can compute the average distance.
\begin{align*}
E\left[\frac{|S_1| + \cdots + |S_{2n}|}{2n} \right]
&= \frac{1}{2n}(E[|S_1|] + \cdots + E[|S_{2n}|]) \\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} E[|S_{2k+1}|] + \sum_{k=1}^n E[|S_{2k}|]\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: But isn't $E[|S_{2m}|]$ the expected distance at the *end* of the walk, and not *during* the walk?

Comment: @tscizzle do you mind writing the random variable you're interested in? The wording of the question is unclear

Comment: I think it would be $\frac{(S_1+...+S_n)}{n}$, using your definition of $S$, since $S$ is the distance from the origin, and I want the expected average distance from the origin of all the positions along the walk.

Comment: @tscizzle $S_i$ is the position of the walk; the distance is $|S_i|$. For example, the random walk could be at position -5, and the distance would be 5. Unless you actually want to take into account it being at a negative location...

Comment: you're 100% right, my bad. there should be absolute-value in there, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

In an arbitrary dimension d:

The average displacement from the origin **during** the walk depends on whether or not the displacement at the **end** of the walk is known. If the displacement at the **end** is **not** known, than the average displacement from the origin **during** the walk is given by:
$$\frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^N \langle R_i \rangle
=\frac{l\sqrt{2}}{d(N+1)}\frac{
\Gamma \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)
}{\Gamma \left( \frac{d}{2}\right)}
\sum_{n=1}^N  \sqrt{n}
$$

---

Let $\vec{R}$ be the end-to-end distance vector of a random walk of fixed step length $|\vec{r}_i| = l$. $\vec{R}$ can then be expressed as $\displaystyle \vec{R} = \sum_{i=1}^N \vec{r}_i$, where $\vec{r}_i$ is the vector of the $i$-th step. The Root-Mean-Square End-to-End Distance is given by $\textrm{RMS}=\sqrt { \langle R^2 \rangle }$. Since the steps are mutually independent, the covariance of two steps $\vec{r}_i$ and $\vec{r}_j$ is zero if $i\neq j$ and $\textrm{Cov}(\vec{r}_i, \ \vec{r}_j)= \textrm{Var}(\vec{r}_i)$ if $i=j$. The variance of $ \vec{r}_i$ can be expressed as $ \textrm{Var}(\vec{r}_i)= \langle   \vec{r}_i \cdot  \vec{r}_i \rangle - \langle   \vec{r}_i \rangle^2$. Due to symmetry $\langle \vec{r}_i \rangle=\vec{0}$ and therefore the variance of 
of $ \vec{r}_i$ is simply $ \textrm{Var}(\vec{r}_i)= \langle   \vec{r}_i \cdot  \vec{r}_i \rangle = |\vec{r}_i|^2 = l^2$. Altogether, the covariance of $\vec{r}_i$ and $\vec{r}_j$ equals $\textrm{Cov}(\vec{r}_i, \ \vec{r}_j)=\delta_{ij}l^2$. The covariance of $\vec{r}_i$ and $\vec{r}_j$ can also be expressed as $\textrm{Cov}(\vec{r}_i, \ \vec{r}_j) = \langle   \vec{r}_i \cdot  \vec{r}_j \rangle - \langle   \vec{r}_i \rangle \cdot \langle   \vec{r}_j \rangle$. Combining the two different expressions for the covariance and using that
$\langle   \vec{r}_i \rangle=0$, results in $\langle   \vec{r}_i \cdot  \vec{r}_j \rangle =\delta_{ij}l^2$. This result can be used to determine the RMS:

$$\textrm{RMS}=\sqrt { \langle R^2 \rangle } = \sqrt { \langle \vec{R} \cdot \vec{R} \rangle } 
=\sqrt { \big\langle  \sum_{i=1}^N \vec{r}_i \cdot  \sum_{j=1}^N \vec{r}_j \big\rangle }
=\sqrt { \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \langle   \vec{r}_i \cdot  \vec{r}_j \rangle }
=\sqrt { \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N l^2 \delta_{ij} + 0^2}= \sqrt { \sum_{i=1}^N l^2}=\sqrt { N l^2}=l\sqrt { N }$$

Let $Z_i$ denote the $i$-th coordinate of the end-to-end distance vector $\vec{R}$ after $N$ steps, and let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ denote the number of steps taken in the $i$-th dimension in the positive and negative direction respectively. Then the set of random variables $\{X_i, Y_i\}_{i=1}^d$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters  $N$ and $\displaystyle p_i=\frac{N}{2d}$. For sufficiently large values of $N$, $\{X_i, Y_i\}_{i=1}^d$ are approximately iid (independent and identically distributed) Poisson random variables with parameters $\displaystyle \lambda_i = \frac{N}{2d}$. For $\lambda > 20$, i.e. $N>40d$, $\textrm{Po}(\lambda) \sim \textrm{N}(\lambda, \lambda)$. $ Z_i = l(X_i - Y_i)$ and therefore  $\displaystyle Z_i \sim \textrm{N}(l(\lambda - \lambda), l^2(\lambda+\lambda))=\textrm{N}(0, 2l\lambda)=\textrm{N}\left(0, \frac{l^2N}{d}\right)$.

$\displaystyle \langle R \rangle
= \langle \sqrt{R^2} \rangle
= \left\langle \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d Z_i^2} \right\rangle$. The square root of a sum of $k$ independent $\textrm{N}(0, 1)$-distributed random variables is distributed according to the chi distribution, $\chi_k$. Therefore $\displaystyle  \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{dZ_i^2}{l^2N}}$ is approximately  $\chi_d$-distributed for large values of $N$. The expected value of a $\chi_k$-distributed random variable
is $\displaystyle \sqrt{2} \frac{
\Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)
}{\Gamma \left( \frac{k}{2}\right)}$.

Hence $\displaystyle \langle R \rangle
=\left\langle\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d Z_i^2}\right\rangle
=\left\langle l \sqrt{\frac{N}{d}} \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d  \frac{dZ_i^2}{l^2N} }\right\rangle
=  l \sqrt{\frac{2N}{d} }\frac{
\Gamma \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)
}{\Gamma \left( \frac{d}{2}\right)}$. \

If the displacement at the **end** is **not** known, than the average displacement from the origin **during** the walk is given by:

$$ \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^N \langle R_i \rangle
=\frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^N l \sqrt{\frac{2n}{d} }\frac{
\Gamma \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)
}{\Gamma \left( \frac{d}{2}\right)}
=
\frac{l\sqrt{2}}{d(N+1)}\frac{
\Gamma \left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)
}{\Gamma \left( \frac{d}{2}\right)}
\sum_{n=1}^N  \sqrt{n}
$$