# Expected value of distance in one-dimensional random walk

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $S_n$ be a one-dimensional random walk; that is, the sum of $n$ i.i.d. coin toss variables $X_1, ..., X_n$ (meaning that $P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=-1)=1/2$). My question is to compute the expected value of $|S_n|$ in an "elementary" form.

I have been doing the calculations myself and in the end I finished with something very similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583702/average-distance-from-origin-in-a-random-walk-on-the-integer-number-line?rq=1), but in the end there is always a series that I am not able to compute. Precisely, it is clear that, assuming $n$ is even, say $n=2m$, then $S_n$ can only take even values, and that
$$P[S_n = 2k] = \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\binom{2m}{m+k}$$

From here it follows that, using that $P[S_n = j] =P[S_n = -j]$,

$$E[|S_{2m}|] = \sum_{k=0}^m (2k)\cdot P[|S_n|=2k] = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{2^{2m-2}} k \binom{2m}{m+k}$$

but it is this sum that I am not able to compute. In particular, is there any "probabilistic" point of view that allows one to calculate the sum right on the spot? Similar to the fact that $2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk$ or something in the same line.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question. $|X_n|=1$ for all $n$. Did you mean you are computing $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i-X_{i-1}|\right]$$

Comment: @SlipEternal sorry, there was a typo. I meant $|S_n|$.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery yes, please let me know about it.

Comment: Whoops! I was making a silly mistake, and I can no longer claim the existence of such a proof.

Comment: I think this gives you what you want: see (33) of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html

Comment: @AaronMontgomery yes, I know about such a proof, but I have the same problem about the summations in (22) and (29). Personally I would like to avoid using gamma functions here, but that is not really a problem.